# Run a TS file every X minutes

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a code file in TS format which I can launch it from command prompt like this

```
npx ts-node maincodes.ts
```

Lets say I dont have access to change anything inside maincodes.ts file and I want it to be launched every X minutes on my machine (It is windows btw and using vs code).

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/using-the-task-scheduler

Answer (score 1):

Assuming youre on a unix terminal:

You need to transpile that .ts file into .js to run it in node, alternatively download something like `ts-node` from npm:

```
npm install -g ts-node
```

Now you need to schedule the task to run every 15 minutes:

Open crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

Add a new line to schedule the script execution. To run the script every 15 minutes, you can add:

```
*/15 * * * * ts-node /path/to/your/file.ts
```

That should use `ts-node` to run your program every 15 minutes.

Comment: I used npm install crontab .... 
it is installed , but crontab -e give me error 'crontab' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: oh I think crontab is not working on windows

Comment: @mhmd correct, it's a unix utility

Answer (score 1):

For windows - open "Task Scheduler" app and add a task to run the command you want whenever you want it to run.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run `maincodes.ts` periodically without modifying the original file you can create `.bat` file to execute the program on a specific interval. Afterwards use Task Scheduler to schedule the script.

script.bat

```
cd /d "C:\pathtoproject" 
npx ts-node maincodes.ts
```

add `@echo off` if you want the commands to not be displayed on the terminal

To schedule the task follow and select our script:

https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/how-to-schedule-a-script-via-windows-task-scheduler/